# remove overlaps string in vector with iterator c++

Tags: c++, string, vector, iterator

i want to remove overlaps string stored in vector<-string> for show only one element.
i sorted vector dictionary order and it work well.
and next for erase, i use code below.

```
  for(auto iter = begin(vec); iter != end(vec); iter++) {
        auto frontIter = (iter + 1);

        if((*iter).compare(*frontIter) == 0) 
            vec.erase(iter);
    }
```

but it erase only one overlap element.
if i input like a a a(3 strings) and all element of vector show a a(2 strings)
i think `vec.erase(iter);` of part have something wrong..

Comment: The `vec.erase()` call invalidates all iterators that refer to (elements of) `vec` at or after `iter`.   Your code is assuming the iterators are still valid, so has undefined behaviour.   In any event, look up the standard algorithm `unique()`.

Comment: @Peter thanks for advice. i will check `unique()` at reference,

Answer (score 1):

Put the elements of the `vector` in a `set` and then put back to `vector` will remove all the duplicates.

```
set<string> s( vec.begin(), vec.end() );
vec.assign( s.begin(), s.end() );
```

If it is necessary to do with iterator

```
set<string> s;
for(auto iter = begin(vec); iter != end(vec); iter++)
{
    s.insert(*iter);
}
vec.assign( s.begin(), s.end() );
```